# SSIS package first business day

Tags: sql

Is there a way to force Sql Server Agent to run a package on the first business day of the month( business day being monday thru friday)?Short of writing out a stored proc which calculates the holidays and weekends?

Thank you very much for your help.

enviroment SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the first business day of the month is something that is defined specifically for an individual business of course it is not possible for the agent to know what you consider to be the first day. If you have a holiday table, it shouldn't be too tought towrite the stored proc and make it the first steps of a job.  Have it return as failed (and thus not go on to step 2 the actual package) if  it isn't the first business day of the month and schedule it to run the first 7 days of the month.